# Limits to load connections for AFCI/GFCI Outlet

Tags: gfci, afci

I am remodeling my basement.  I will have 4 separate electrical circuits.

1. 20A Circuit to Bathroom
2. 20A Circuit to Laundry room
3. 15A Circuit for left side outlets / lights
4. 15A Circuit for right side outlets / lights

Each of the 15A circuits runs are 40+ feet long, with 5 outlets and 2 overhead lights.

The question is - Can I use an AFCI/GFCI outlet at the first outlet and run the remaining outlets/lights from the AFCI/GFCI load output.  I was told that there is a limit to the total wire length from the load.  The instruction for the outlet does not address this issue.  (see link below)

Leviton Dual Function AFCI/GFCI http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ProductDetail.jsp?partnumber=AGTR1-W&section=76663&minisite=10251

Answer (score 4):

Your plan will work. Some AFCI's have length restrictions to the first outlet Branch circuit 50' for 14 awg wire and 70' for 12awg NEC 210.12.A.3.B & 210.12.A.4.B. using one installed at the first outlet and installed according to manufacturer instructions you can complete your plan within code.